# Windows 7 Python 3 find keyword in file show filename and path

Tags: python, python-3.x

Would like to use a text file containing multiple windows path/filename.txt files and feed into a for loop which would then take each path leading to a filename.txt and search it for a word. This would happen for each path to a file in the filename.txt file.
So far this part is functioning:

```
with open ("filename.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
    print (data)
```

Printing the data gives me this:
    The results of printing out the contents of the variable, "data" looks like:

```
c:/temp\Txt_folder\3rd_lyr_fldr\3rd_infiles.txt
c:/temp\Txt_folder\3rd_lyr_fldr\3rd_ListFile.txt
c:/temp\Txt_folder\3rd_lyr_fldr\3rd_new_filename1.txt
```

This part of script ,shown below, does not work. The data shown above is not fed into the for loop (shown below) one line at a time but rather one continuous column or at least
that is the way print(data) shows it on my screen.

```
for line in data:
    if re.search(r"something",line):
        print(line)
```

How can this me accomplished.

Comment: You have to *open* a file before searching its contents. All you're doing now is searching the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that basically does what you want:

```
keyword = 'whatever'
with open ('filename.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
    for filename in (line.strip() for line in myfile):
        with open(filename, 'rt') as file:
            for line in file:
                if keyword in line:
                    print(line, end='')
```

Comment: WOW, have a long way to go before any of those kind of answers come to me. Glad to be learning Python with the help of this website and its contributors. Keeps you on the right track(me).

Comment: And by adding print filename it tells me where the file is located:)

Comment: Exactly. Also, If you only care whether the keyword appears at least once in the file, you could speed up the search by adding a `break` statement after printing off whatever information you want displayed.

Comment: It worked great on my test path which was C:/temp but when I tossed this path to it C:/users/rudy it failed with the following error:

Comment: Martineau, your solution worked fine with the text.txt file containing paths to my C:/temp folder but when I created a new text.txt file which included C:/users/rudy it failed.   File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 528: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Without seeing a full traceback, I'm guessing that adding an `encoding='utf8'` keyword argument to the `open(filename, 'rt')` call may help.

Comment: Here is the entire error code:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\Users\Rudy\Text_file.py", line 41, in <module>
    for line in (line.strip() for line in file):
  File "C:\Users\Rudy\Text_file.py", line 41, in <genexpr>
    for line in (line.strip() for line in file):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 528: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Thought about this after doing some more reading and it might be due to a txt file either containing language other the english or a corrupted file. Wish the error code would point me to the file in question. BTW tried encoding='utf8' but no luck but I might have messed up the syntax. Will try again guessing it goes like this : with open ('filename.txt', 'rt' encoding='utf8')

Comment: Yes, that sounds likely to be the problem. The correct syntax (and line to change) is `open(filename, 'rt', encoding='utf8')` — note comma following the `'rt'`.

Comment: Sorry but noticed two items in your response, first is it utf-8 or utf8. Secondly can not find the 'rt' you use for opening files what does the 't' do?

Comment: This turned out to fix the problem:

Comment: There is on last error when running this script it happens when it attempts to open a file in C:/$Windows.~BT\\Sources\\SafeOS\\SafeOS.Mount\\Windows\\System32\\hwcompat.txt' Something to the affect system can not open file. Need to figure this out now.

Comment: That last error may be because the script needs administrative privileges to open that file. Also, the `'rt'` open the file in text mode as opposed to binary mode. In the former, line endings of all platforms are translated when read into single character `'\n'` newlines (and translated to the proper platform-specific convention when written). I'm not sure it matters that much in this case, but it shouldn't cause any harm.

Comment: It is working now. Next step add Reg Expr's to the search keyword Thank you for your help.